# Changing stdout in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

By setting `export GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT=777` I want to change my stdout in gfortran. If I run the program

```
    program main
       implicit none

       write (*,*) "*"
       write (6,*) "6"
       write (777,*) "777"
    end program main
```

it will output

```
> $ ./a.out                                                                                           
 777
```

and create a file:

```
> $ cat fort.6                                                                                        
 *
 6
```

Why isn't `*` forwarded to the stdout (now 777) anymore? Is this a gfortran bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: It would likely make more sense to ask the gfortran developers about the "intended behaviour" directly. They do come here from time to time, but the mailing list is a much surer bet.

Comment: I don't believe that fortran's behaviour is at odds with the standard, thought it may be at odds with one's expectations.  The standard requires that `*` indicate the same output unit as one that is pre-connected for output.  The standard is silent on what the unit numbers of the pre-connected units should or may be.  However the intrinsic named constant `OUTPUT_UNIT`, which is defined in the module `iso_fortran_env`, should be the unit to which `*` refers, that much the standard does mandate.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, wouldn't you expect in this case, then, that `*` refers to unit 777?  And so the output should appear on stdout and not in `fort.6`?  Or are you saying that unit 6 is still the one _pre-connected_?

Comment: I'm saying that my expectations are irrelevant, and that I cannot determine from the standard that `gfortran` is behaving wrongly.  Oddly perhaps, but not wrongly.  What does your reading of the standard tell you ?

Comment: Ah, @HighPerformanceMark, I read the comment as being more pro-active than you may have intended.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the behaviour is as expected. The following paragraphs are of interest here:

> `GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT`: Unit number for standard output
>   This environment variable can be used to select the unit number **preconnected to standard output**. This must be a positive integer. The default value is 6.
>   **<sub>source: [GCC Gfortran Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gfortran/GFORTRAN_005fSTDOUT_005fUNIT.html#GFORTRAN_005fSTDOUT_005fUNIT)</sub>**

So this just states that `/dev/stdout` will be connected to the unit number `GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT`.

The Fortran Standard makes the following statements:

> **9.5 File connection**
>   *9.5.1 Referring to a file*
>   4 In a WRITE statement, an io-unit that is an asterisk identifies an external unit that is preconnected for sequential formatted output. This unit is also
>   identified by the value of the named constant `OUTPUT_UNIT` of the intrinsic module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`.
>
> **Note 9.15:** Even though `OUTPUT_UNIT` is connected to a separate file on each image, it is expected that the processor **could** merge the sequences of records from these files into a single sequence of records that is sent to the
>   physical device associated with this unit, **such as the user’s terminal**.
>
> **<sub>source: [Fortran 2008 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf)</sub>**

All we know is that <asterisk> (ergo `OUTPUT_UNIT`) are preconnected to a unit for sequential formatted output. The standard makes no statement what this external unit is. It makes no reference to `/dev/stdout`. The standard actually explicitly mentions in a note that the user's terminal is a **possible** pre-connected unit, it could as well have been your printer.

So in the end, by setting `GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT=777`, you just preconnect unit 777 to `/dev/stdout` and <asterisk> will be preconnected to an external unit for sequential output (i.e. in this case fort.6)

Comment: This seems a strange reading to me. There are many places where the terminology in the Fortran standard and in the GCC documentation or error messages slightly differ even if they are meant to denote the same thing (argument vs. parameter, for example).

Comment: And I would rather stay away from Note 9.15, that is about the outputs of other images.

Comment: @VladimirF True, but the note "implies" that the user's terminal is a possible "output-object" which could be preconnected to `output_unit`. I have not found any reference stating that asterisk is connected to your terminal-output (ignoring redirections here). I always found the Fortran standard incredibly "generic" (and sometimes vague).

Comment: I do agree the behaviour is allowed. But whether it is expected...  I do not know. I think redirecting OUTPUT_UNIT together with * to 777 would be equally allowed and one may have equally good reasons to expect that.